# Draper Semianalytical Satellite Theory (DSST) C/C++ version

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, propagation

Anyone knows where one could find the Draper Semianalytical Satellite Theory (DSST) semi-analytical propagator code in C/C++?
I know Orekit includes the Java version inside its code.

An in general if someone knows about open-source implementation of semi-analytical orbit propagator.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The way I read the literature, the Java Orekit version is the only publicly accessible version.  If I am wrong, someone please tell me!

The C++ conversion was done later (2017-2020 vs. 2012-2015), by a group led by Professor [Juan Félix San Juan](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juan-San-Juan) of [Universidad de la Rioja](https://www.unirioja.es/) in Spain.  They used to (2012) have a web site (http://tastrody.unirioja.es) where anyone could use [standalone Fortran77 DSST remotely](https://amostech.com/TechnicalPapers/2012/Astrodynamics/SAN-JUAN.pdf), but it doesn't seem to be there anymore.  If you can find a copy of San Juan, López, Setty, and Cefola, "Validation of DSST C/C++ against original Fortran version: integration test", *AIAA Scitech 2020 Forum*, https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2020-0955, it has a number of interesting things to say, but it doesn't contain any code as such.  More recent papers, like San Juan, López, Pérez, and Cefola, "Including the closed form $J_2^2$ effect in DSST", *AAS 21-233*, have stopped talking about C++ implementation, and moved on to adding new features.  I'm not sure to what extent they are trying to keep the Fortran, C++, and Java versions synchronized with each other.  To actually get your hands on the non-Java code, I would recommend contacting the authors directly.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! It is what I have seen around more or less. I need to implement an analytical or semi-analytical propagator, and I was looking around if something was already implemented, better if in C or Python. Anyone knows better the state of art about that?